# Count quantity of specific product in views

Tags: 7, views, commerce, importing-exporting

I'm using *Views* and *Views Data Export* to create a downloadable CSV of store orders logged in *Commerce*.

I want to create a column that counts the quantity for a specific commerce product (defined by SKU) in the order (so needs to go through line items).

Any ideas of how to do this?